# Display heterogenous data from Perl array of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures

Pseudocode

```
i=0;
array $id;
array $name; 
array $size;
$array[$i] = ($id, $name, $size);
```

where I would like to get output

```
-----------------------------
ID | Name | Size
-----------------------------
$id(0) | $name(0) | $size(0)
$id(1) | $name(1) | $size(1)
$id(2) | $name(2) | $size(2)
...    | ...      | ...
-----------------------------
```

Pseudocode for printing out datastructure

```
for $row in $array:
    for $col in $row: 
        print $col, "|"; 
    end; 
    print "\n;
end
```

where I am uncertain about referencing to a variable from inside for-loop to outside for-loop. 
There is finite number of variables but I may need to do statistical analysis based on them later in R. 
The database connection, for instance between postreSQL and R is still about in beta phase [here](https://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/). 
So I would like to keep data as raw.

How can you choose better the data structure for such data and its needed processes?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-ARRAYS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two similar data structures in perl.

You have the `list` which is an ordered sequence of scalars. And you have the `hash` which is an unordered group of key-value pairs.

So with that in mind - it *might* be worth using key-value pairs, if your 'id' is a key field. (Then you can sort on it trivially - indeed, you have to to produce ordered output)

But in your example - you don't really need to access 'outer' loop from 'inner':

```
my @LOL = ( 
                [ 'id', 'name', 'size' ],
                [ 'id2', 'name2', 'size2' ], 
          );

foreach my $row ( @LOL ) {
   print join ( "|", @$row ), "\n"; 
}
```

Is a bit of a simplistic example of how this works.

However your data *could* be keyvalue - so you might do it like this instead:

```
my %hash = (
    'id1' => {
        'name' => 'myname',
        'size' => 'mysize',
    },
    'id2' => {
        'name' => 'my2name',
        'size' => 'my2size',
    },
);

my @columns = qw ( name size );

foreach my $id ( sort keys %hash ) {
    print join( "|", $id, @{ $hash{$id} }{@columns} ), "\n";
}
```

That's probably not necessary unless you're going to need to maintain the relationships though.

Comment: Arrays are not lists :-)

Comment: Assume your table has 10 variables. I just looked that I can still keep the data normalized  with the hash table structure. My keys `[ 'FileID', 'FileSize', 'EventSize', 'AmountEvents', 'EventSelection', 'FileHeaderSize', 'ffff', 'fafa', 'strings-td-3']`. Otherwise, the hash table can become challenging if unnormalized data, I think.

Comment: If situation that I should describe the event, then I should make another table to keep situation normalized. I wonder how well another hash-table  with the first hash-table would survive.